# rounding 1 to have two floating digits

Tags: python, floating-point, integer, rounding

```
'''
Your task is to write a function which returns the sum of following series upto nth term(parameter).

Series: 1 + 1/4 + 1/7 + 1/10 + 1/13 + 1/16 +...
'''
```

Kind of non-trivial but I tried to use `round(1,2)` to show `1.00` but it shows `1.0`, what can I use to show `1.00` in Python?

```
def series_sum(n):
    # Happy Coding ^_^
    sum = 0
    for i in range(n):
        sum += 1/(1+(3*i))
    return round(sum, 2)
```

This is a return value for a coding challenge in [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/555eded1ad94b00403000071/train/python) not a print. so it is supposed to be return and you just write the method.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: 3.4.3 is the version

Comment: Are you sure they want a float back? That doesn't really make sense. What's the actual issue/error you're getting?

Comment: That is what the question want!! please look at the details I have added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#format) function:

```
return format(sum, '.2f')
```

Comment: @MonaJalal note that this is **still a string**, you're not returning a float. And the site you're using isn't publicly-visible so more info in the question would have helped.

Answer (score 2):

For numerical calculation, the digits after the decimals should not matter. I believe you want a string representation with 2 decimal places.

In Python 2.x, you'd do:

```
>>> "%.2f"%1.0
'1.00'
```

In Python3.x, you'd do:

```
>>> "{:.2f}".format(1.0)
'1.00'
```

Comment: this is a return value not a print

Comment: I showed you the way to convert it to a string with a given number of decimal points. What do you with it -- return it, or print it -- is up to you.